# How do you step into and debug .NET request validation in MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, request-validation

If this is possible, please could someone let me know how I can either set a breakpoint on request validation in .NET or view errors thrown by it?

The request validation is happening during an AJAX request from one of my views but I've not been able to view the errors that are being passed back (It's happening, as expected when I attempt to post HTML and javascript) But I like being able to dig a bit and view the messages that are being produced.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debugging request validation should be possible if you download the MVC source code from [here](https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/), and then enable debugging on it in Visual Studio. Information on how to do that can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms241613.aspx).

Comment: Looks like a bit of a treasure trove for me to get into! Thanks.

Comment: There's nothing to download for the MVC project. All releases are empty. Can you please explain in your answer what exactly I need to do to debug MVC? VS 2010 (MVC 4.0) or 2013 (5.2.3) are fine.